# Decompose the function to power series $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2},x_o=0$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

We have the $f(x)$ function to represent it as  power series with center at defined point $x_0$:

> $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2},x_o=0$$

Also we should define the radius of convergence.

It seems like we should use the formula:

$$\frac{1}{1-t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n,0<t<1$$

I tried to use it this way:

$$f(x)=\{t=x+x^2\}=\frac{1}{1-t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (x+x^2)^n$$

Then we can found radius of convergence using following formula:
$$ \mathbb {C}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|b_n|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|x+x^2|^n}=|x+x^2|$$

Convergence is true, while: $|x+x^2|<1$

Solving this, we get:
$$-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{5}}2<x<-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{5}}2$$

So, it seems that we got $x_0=- \frac12$, but this is not $0$ ($x_0=0$)

I got this problem from "Collection of problems in mathematical analysis, Kudryavtsev. Book 2.". Under the theme "Power series".

Comment: Hint: Expand the series for the first few terms and you should find the sequence to be familiar.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{5}{4}-\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{4}{5}\frac{1}{1-\left(\sqrt\frac{4}{5}\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2}$

Comment: @Matematleta I tried replace $t=\sqrt\frac{4}{5}(x+\frac{1}{2})$ and got expression: $f(x)=\frac{4}{5}(\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n)\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-t)}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite,

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{1}{(1-\frac xa)(1-\frac xb)}$$

where $a=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ and $b=\frac{-1-\sqrt 5}{2}$ are the roots of $1-x-x^2 = 0$. Then, decompose the denominator,

$$f(x) = \frac{p}{1-\frac xa} + \frac{q}{1-\frac xb}$$

where $p =\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{10}$ and $q= \frac{5-\sqrt 5}{10}$. Now, expand the two terms separately,

$$\frac{1}{1-\frac xa}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{a^n}, \>\>\>
\frac{1}{1-\frac xb}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{b^n} $$

The first expansion converges if $|x| < a = \frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2}$ and the second expansion converges if $|\frac xb| < 1$ and then $ |x| < |b| = \frac{\sqrt 5 +1}{2}$.

$ \frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2}<\frac{\sqrt 5 +1}{2}$, thus, both converge if

$$|x| < \frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2}$$

Add the two expansions together  to get the power series of $f(x)$,

$$f(x) = p\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{a^n} + q\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{b^n}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac {p}{a^n} + \frac{q}{b^n}\right)x^n $$

where the values of $p$, $q$, $a$ and $b$ have been derived earlier.

Comment: It is not helps, because: the last line is not logically connected with other; this series's radius is not correct, also center of convergence is hard to get

Comment: The power series converges if $|x|<\frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2}$. Please see the added explanation in the answer.

Comment: sure, center of convergence is true, but: we know that if we will summ two not convergence series we can get convergence series. But You hold just convergence series, and summ it. Of course, summ is converges, but we can miss some area

Comment: It is generally true that sum of two non-converging series may converge. For the expansion in question, the answer derived an explicit power series with respect to $x_0=0$ with all the coefficients explicitly given. I’d conjecture that it is an unique expansion and there are no alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Some **hints** and additional info referring to comments:

- If there is any convergent power series expansion of $f$ around $x=0$, then it must satisfy
  $$f(x) - xf(x) - x^2 f(x) \stackrel{!}{=} 1 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=0}a_nx^n - \sum_{n=0}a_nx^{n+1}- \sum_{n=0}a_nx^{n+2} \stackrel{!}{=} 1$$
- Writing as a single power series gives
  $$a_0 + (a_1 -a_0)x + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(a_n - a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})x^n \stackrel{!}{=}1$$
- This gives a recursion for $a_n$ which turns out to be the recursion for the Fibonacci-sequence $F_n$:
  $$a_0=1, a_1 = a_0, a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2} \; (n\geq 2)\Rightarrow \boxed{a_n = F_n}$$
- The explicit formula for $F_n$ (which can be found, for example, by solving the recursion) is
  $$F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left( \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n - \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n \right)$$
- Since $\boxed{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} = \phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$ (the golden ratio), you get the radius of convergence
  $$\boxed{R = \frac{1}{\phi}}$$

Comment: That's interesting, but where we can get this formula? $f(x) - xf(x) - x^2 f(x) = 1 $

Comment: @EgorRandomize : 
You just multiply $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$ by $1-x-x^2$. Besides this you know that if there is a power series representation around $x=0$, then this power series must satisfy the condition $(1-x-x^2)f(x) = 1$.

Comment: okay, that's clear. But the next part is not clear. I can got an=Fn as some function. We can get radius, using formula. But why phi is equals to this fraction?

Comment: @EgorRandomize : 
When you rewrite the sum of the 3 power series as a single one you get
$$a_0 + (a_1 -a_0)x + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(a_n - a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})x^n \stackrel{!}{=}1$$ It follows $a_0=1, a_1 = a_0, a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. This is exactly the recursion for the Fibonacci sequence which is usually denoted by $F_n$. This sequence has the explicit formula $F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left( \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n - \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n \right)$. From this follows immediately that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: May be it will better if you update your answer with this tips and notes

Comment: @EgorRandomize Done. I didn't have much time when I wrote the first answer as a list of hints. But you are right that it is better to update with some more info.